# AttributeError: module 'skimage.measure' has no attribute 'marching_cubes'

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

when I'm executing one of code that I found from the web it's given me "AttributeError: module 'skimage.measure' has no attribute 'marching_cubes'". Do you have any idea to fix this?

Executed code segment:

```
from skimage import measure
def make_mesh(image, threshold=+30, step_size=1):
 print "Transposing surface"


p = image.transpose(2, 1, 0)

print "Calculating surface"
verts, faces, norm, val = measure.marching_cubes(p, threshold, step_size=step_size, allow_degenerate=True)
return verts, faces
```

Comment: Just print `dir(measure)`

Answer (score 8):

In the new version, there are two methods [`marching_cubes_lewiner`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner) and [`marching_cubes_classic`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes_classic). But classic doesn't take `step_size` parameter. You can try this:

```py
measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(p, threshold, step_size=step_size, allow_degenerate=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used [the `marching_cubes_lewiner` function](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner) to solve the problem. Please refer following code line.

```
print("Calculating surface")
verts, faces, norm, val = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(p, threshold, step_size=step_size, allow_degenerate=True)
return verts, faces
```

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if it included an explanation of ***how*** the `marching_cube_lewiner` function solved the problem. Maybe also some sample code?

Comment: Updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In version 0.19 there is only `marching_cubes` method. So try to change `marching_cube_lewiner` with `marching_cubes` and pay attention with the parameters.

reference:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner

Answer (score 0):

You can use **marching_cubes_classic**(p, threshold)

Answer (score 0):

Because the scikit-image version is too old, please replace the version above 0.16 to solve it.

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
pip install scikit-image==0.17.1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).